# Как собрать все селекторы набора?

Tags: javascript, jquery

есть вот такой блок с меню

```
 <div class="leftmenu">         
  <ul>
      <ul>
        <li><p><span onclick="show_menu(1)">Хирургия</span></p></li>
        <li><p><span onclick="show_menu(6)">Эндодонтия</span></p></li>
        <li><p><span onclick="show_menu(9)">Ортопедия</span></p></li>
        <li><p><span onclick="show_menu(15)">Терапия</span></p></li>
    </ul>
 </ul>          
 </div>
```

как зацепить все `span`ы`? и задать им например background:red;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('.leftmenu ul span').css({background: 'red'})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="leftmenu">         
  <ul>
      <ul>
        <li><p><span onclick="show_menu(1)">Хирургия</span></p></li>
        <li><p><span onclick="show_menu(6)">Эндодонтия</span></p></li>
        <li><p><span onclick="show_menu(9)">Ортопедия</span></p></li>
        <li><p><span onclick="show_menu(15)">Терапия</span></p></li>
    </ul>
 </ul>          
 </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

**Javascript**

```
const listItems = document.querySelectorAll('.leftmenu span');
for (let i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
  listItems[i].style.background = 'red';
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.leftmenu span').each(function(){$(this).css('background','red')});
```

Comment: а как это на jquery написать?

Comment: Обновил код, сверху чистый javascript, снизу jQuery